# How to merge close enough points in 3D points cloud by their mean value

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a sets of 3D points which are from repeated scan of a static plane from a LIDAR device. Due to the sensor error, points in each scan are slightly offset-ed. And I would like to have an averaged result where close enough points (e.g. distance <= sensor error) are averaged.
For example, different colors means different repeat times, and the points within each circle needs to be averaged.

I know the easiest way is just a nested loop to check the distance, but that is not very efficient. I am using PCL and I wonder if there is a quicker way to do such thing.

[image]

Comment: You are looking for [pcl::VoxelGrid](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php) filter. Set the leaf sizes to the resolution of the point cloud.

Comment: @kanstar That looks like a good answer. Could you post it with instructions on how to use it with multiple point clouds? :)

Comment: @KunalTyagi Well, SO is not a 'write code for me please" platform. If he shows us what he has done so far, we can help him whit that. There a a lot of tutorials on the PCL homepage where he can see example code.

Comment: That's true. That being said SO also says not to just refer to links in answers. Meta: Does this imply lots of questions are 'unanswered' but actually have a valid answer in comments?